# lseek error when -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 is used on solaris

Tags: c++, c, solaris

I am using `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` flag while compiling my application on Unix. It gets built properly on `RHEL`, `SuSE`, `HP-uX` and `AIX`.

On Solaris, I am getting an error for following:

```
long lPos = 0L;
long UTMPSIZE = sizeof(struct utmp);
int fd = 0;

fd = open("/etc/utmp", O_RDONLY);
UTMPSIZE = sizeof(struct utmpx);
lPos = lseek(fd, -UTMPSIZE, SEEK_END); // error: conversion from `long int' to non-scalar type `off_t' requested
```

I read somewhere that using `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, the long gets #defined to `off_t`. 
If that is so, why this error happens?

I wrote the same steps in a cpp program, compiled and executed on a soalris system, and it works. However only while compiling the application, the error is seen.

This is what i have in types.h:

```
#if __STDC__ - 0 == 0 && !defined(_NO_LONGLONG)
typedef long long               longlong_t;
typedef unsigned long long      u_longlong_t;
#else
/* used to reserve space and generate alignment */
typedef union {
        double  _d;
        int32_t _l[2];
} longlong_t;
typedef union {
        double          _d;
        uint32_t        _l[2];
} u_longlong_t;
#endif  /* __STDC__ - 0 == 0 && !defined(_NO_LONGLONG) */

#ifndef _OFF_T
#define _OFF_T

#if defined(_LP64) || _FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 32
typedef long            off_t;          /* offsets within files */
#elif _FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 64
typedef longlong_t      off_t;          /* offsets within files */
#endif

#if defined(_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE)
#ifdef _LP64
typedef off_t           off64_t;        /* offsets within files */
#else
typedef longlong_t      off64_t;        /* offsets within files */
#endif
#endif  /* _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE */

#endif /* _OFF_T */
```

If I use long long in code, the error is now changed to "long long int".

To solve above problem, I have added #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64. It was found that in one of the header same flag value was set to 32. I don't know what happened but, using compile time flag did not override that #define. I then added following after the #include:

```
#ifdef <SunOS>
#undef _FILE_OFFSET_BITS
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#endif
```

This rectifies the compile time error. But now there is another problem, the stat structure members after stat() call are not getting populated properly. I have no clue why is it happening so.

Any help here is much appreciated..

Comment: http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/largefile/solaris.print.html

Comment: In the link i posted in earlier comment, it is mentioned that long is #defined to off_t, so it should not be explicitly required to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The "non-scalar type" part of the error message is suspicious, as it implies that off_t is being implemented as some kind of struct instead of a 64-bit integer.

Is gcc up-to-date on the Solaris machine?  Specifically, if you are using gcc 4.3.0 on Solaris, you may be experiencing GCC bug 30513 (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30513).  If you look at comment 9 in the bug report, you can see they get a very similar error: "conversion from 'jlong' to non-scalar type 'off_t' requested".

Comment: gcc version is older than 4.3.0. Its 3.4.2 :(.